# Excel Launching Blank Workbook On Opening Custom File

Tags: php, excel, file-generation

I work on a website, and up until Monday we were able to download a custom excel file sheet and display it. At this point, whenever we try to open it, it launches a blank, grayed-out workbook if Excel is not currently running, and nothing if it is. I have tried editing the content type to no avail. I have tried creating documents with older data that worked at the time and it doesn't work. Nothing has changed on the file system regarding this in a month, and it only just started. Here is the current code used to generate the file:

```
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Cache-Control: private', false);
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fname);
                ob_clean();
                ob_flush();
                echo $somecontent;
                exit;
```

[Here is what happens when I try to open the created file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8yvY.png)

The only way I have found that fixes this currently is to open the file in Notepad++, edit it, and save it, which then allows it to open properly in Excel.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: So because the comments below didn't help much, I took a look around and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUPiuk5oB4w), and upon disabling those three options I could open the files again without having to go through Notepad++ first. I then narrowed down the field that was causing issues to "Protect files originating from the internet" even though before they worked fine.

Comment: Has this happened any other time? I also have 2016 Excel, and it launched a blank workbook like that for me too. It might be a more broad issue than your code generating the file.  Does [any of this](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+2016+creates+blank+workbook) help/sound familiar?

Comment: This is a common problem that often involves your PERSONAL.xlsb workbook. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/879043/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-opening-a-second-blank-window-when-opening-a-file-from).

Comment: @BruceWayne It has not. Since I do not use Windows Explorer (I use Chrome) the first 2 steps don't help me, and I tried steps 3 and 4 on a coworkers computer and it is still generating the blank workbook.

Comment: @AlexisOlson There is no file in that folder when I went to search for it. Also, there is only one workbook being created, not two, so that doesn't appear to be my issue.